# Query DataBase With PHP + AJAX/JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, refresh

liked to help me. I have a form, and when I write the ID of a user, displays a div with user data with that ID without refreshing the page. How can I do?

MY Form:

```
            <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validar(this)" id="form_aviso" class="form-validate">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_send" value="send" />
                    <b><span name="user">ID Utilizador:</span></b>
                <input type="text" name="iduser" class="iduser" id="iduser" />
                    <input type="submit" class="botao" align="right" value="Submeter" name="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/04/ajax-add-delete-sql-records-jquery-php

Comment: Whoops wrong link, this article should help: http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Since you are mentioning ajax in your title, it sounds like you already know how the basics for how to do this.  Show what you have tried and if you are having a specific problem, then ask about that problem.  As it stands, it doesn't look like you've even tried, and your current question is far too broad.

Answer (score -2):

in jQuery:

```
var user_id = $("#id_of_that_field").val()
```

or:

```
$.post("<server>/get_user_info",{user_id:user_id},function(data){
    $("#result_div").html(data) 
})
```

Comment: The OP wants to fetch data from a database table for a given ID, and then display that data to the use. How does this do any of that?